# Scanner will not scan negative numbers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to scan a negative number using the Scanner class in Java.

I have this input file:

> 1
>
> -1,2,3,4

My code is as follows:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data/input.txt"));
    int i = input.nextInt();
    input.useDelimiter(",|\\s*"); //for future use
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(a);
```

My expected output should be

> 1
>
> -1

instead I get an error (Type Mismatch).

When I do

```
String a = input.next();
```

instead of

```
int a = input.nextInt();
```

I no longer get an error and I instead get

> 1
>
> -

Comment: `input.nextInt();` reads *only* the integer value, the `\n` won't be consumed.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why when I do 'code'(input.next()) it doesn't read the \n but the "-" rather.

Comment: That is because it skips the delimiter, `\n` (newline), which is a whitespace character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The delimiter is either a comma or 0 or more whitespace ('\s') characters.  The `*` means "0 or more".  The `Scanner` found "0 or more" whitespace characters in between the `-` and the `1`, so it split those characters, eventually leading to the input mismatch exception.

You will want to have 1 or more whitespace characters as a delimiter, so change the `*` to a `+` to reflect that intention.

```
input.useDelimiter(",|\\s+");
```

When making this change, I get your expected output:

```
1
-1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cannot believed I overlooked this. I am having trouble finding documentation on these \s patterns and stuff. Do you know what I would search?

Comment: Please see [the `Pattern` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  It goes into great detail about regular expression patterns.